# How would I reference a WPF ItemsControl in a static method?

Tags: c#, wpf

The idea is that I'm trying to just add text blocks to a list in WPF.

Here's my XAML code:

```xml
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" Name="PushOutput" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PushText}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

So there you can see I'm trying to allow for a dynamic list where they just go under each other.

Here's my C# code:

```cs
public PushOutputStuff()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    cmdStartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
    cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmdStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmdStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    Process cmdProcess = new Process();
    cmdProcess.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;
    cmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived += cmd_Error;
    cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += cmd_DataReceived;
    cmdProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    cmdProcess.Start();
    cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    cmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

    //Execute ping bing.com
    cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("ping www.bing.com");
    
    //Execute exit.
    cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");                  

    cmdProcess.WaitForExit();
}

public void AddToLogThing(string data)
{
    List<PushOutputt> logger = new List<PushOutputt>();
    logger.Add(new PushOutputt() { PushText = data });
    PushOutput.ItemsSource = logger;
}

static void cmd_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Output from other process");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

    // This is where I'm having issues
    // Each time it gets mad at me because it's non static
    // is there any way I could try to reference the xaml object "PushOutput" here?
    AddToLogThing(e.Data);
}

static void cmd_Error(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error from other process");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}

class PushOutputt
{
    public string PushText { get; set; }
}
```

I 'm trying to set up some sort of simple logging system where each text block that's created here is one line of the log and it just doesn't want to work because I can't add a line and update the itemscontrol list within the static data received methods

Comment: `static` methods are not instance-specific so any code they contain that is instance-specific must act on a parameter and you then pass in an instance-specific argument when you call the method.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that acting on the View like you are doing flies in the face of the MVVM pattern (but not the MVPVM pattern).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `PushOutputStuff`-object with `Application.Current.Dispatcher`:

```
public static void AddToLogThing(string data)
{
    var logger = new List<PushOutputt>();

    logger.Add(new PushOutputt() { PushText = data });

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(
        () =>
        {
            if(Application.Current.MainWindow is PushOutputStuff pos)
            {
                if(pos.PushOutput.ItemsSource is List<PushOutputt> srcLst)
                {
                    logger.AddRange(srcLst);
                }
                pos.PushOutput.ItemsSource = logger;
            }
        }
        ));
}
```

Comment: quite strange.. I get the same error here as I did with @Clemens

Comment: I have updated the answer. The same you can do in another answers.

Comment: I still get the same error "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'" I'm not quite sure how to get around it

Comment: This answer is terrible, compared to not making the simple mistake of declaring the OutputDataReceived handler method static. It should not have beed accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The OutputDataReceived handler method does not need to be static.

Since it is called in a background thread, i.e. a thread other than the UI thread, you would also have to use the UI thread's Dispatcher to access the ItemsControl.

```
// not static!
//
private void cmd_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => AddToLogThing(e.Data));
}
```

Or perhaps just

```
private void cmd_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        PushOutput.Items.Add(new PushOutput { PushText = e.Data }));
}
```

Comment: See my issue with that is that I get this error when I try it: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'"

Comment: That's a totally different problem than what you have originally asked for, and you could have found a solution easily on StackOverflow, but see the edited answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, Thank you for the help anyways!

Comment: You're welcome. Do you actually understand what I am saying in my answer? Just remove the `static` keyword and you are done. The approach in the answer you accepted is far too complicated. It makes no sense at all to access `Application.Current.MainWindow` just because you did not know that the OutputDataReceived handler method does not need to be static.

Comment: The accepted answer to the question as it is formulated is correct. Your answer to the asked question _How would I reference a WPF ItemsControl in a static method_ is wrong! There are a lot of ways how code can be improved, but for this aim there is codereview site.

Comment: @Rekshino But you *do* understand that OP made a simple mistake by declaring the OutputDataReceived handler method static? You are not going to tell me that your workaround is in any way comparable to not making the error in the first place. It is just terrible.

Comment: On SO there are sometimes question of theoretical nature. Try to watch it from this perspective if you can.

Comment: @Rekshino Now it's getting ridiculous, and you know that very well. The one and only perspective here is that OP is unexperienced, and doesn't understand why they wrote `static` at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass your own parameters to your cmd_DataReceived function

Works like this:

```
cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) => cmd_DataReceived(sender, e, "foobar");
```

```
private static void cmd_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e, string foo)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

So instead of string foobar you can pass in what ever you like.
But keep in mind (Most likely not a problem in your case) unsubscribing with "-=" is a little bit ugly.